# WP_Query or get_posts?

Tags: wp-query

When using the 'fields' => 'ids' parameter, is it better to create a new WP_Query in the code below rather than doing get_posts?

How would the loop look if I used WP_Query?

```
function myplugin_delete_image_items( $postid ) {

    $args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'myplugin_image_item', 
        'cache_results' => false,   // Disable caching, used for one-off queries
        'no_found_rows' => true,    // We don't need pagination, so disable it
        'fields'        => 'ids',   // Returns post IDs only
        'meta_query'    => array(
                                array(
                                'key'     => 'myplugin_image_id',
                                'value'   => $postid,
                                'compare' => 'LIKE' 
                                )
        )                   
    );

    $image_item_ids = get_posts( $args ); 
    foreach( $image_item_ids as $image_item_id )  {          
            $purge = wp_delete_post( $image_item_id, true ); // delete the image item, skipping trash    
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: Better by what criteria?

Comment: Performance wise.

Comment: `get_posts` itself just creates a new `WP_Query`, all parameters being equal it's exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`get_posts()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_posts) simply uses a `WPQuery` object and sets a few default values. In general the values it sets make it *mildly* more performant. But I wouldn't worry to much about it.

`get_posts()` is simplier so as a rule of thumb if you don't need any of the more involved features of `WP_Query` (including pagination) - then stick with it. But largely comes down to personal preference.

I would leave your example as is. Though you don't need to explicitly set all the values as `get_posts' sets some by default.

Answer (score 1):

If you use WP_Query and create a new object you wont touch the main query keeping it clean. Its safe to use anywhere. Its more complicated but gives you more control and power.

Comment: Actually here is a useful post http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts

Comment: how would loop look if I used WP_Query (considering I am using the 'fields' => 'ids' parameter?

Comment: Something like..

`$delete_images = new WP_Query($args);

while($delete_images->have_posts()){
  $delete_images->the_post();
  wp_delete_post( get_the_ID(), true );
}`

Comment: Actually that didn't work as the_post is not available (I believe) when using the 'fields' => 'ids' paramter.